# Some concerns about AJAX and PHP and how to set multiple parameters in search variable

Tags: php, ajax, dom

OKay, so this is my problem. I've got a AJAX-script with a variable searchResult that i want to fetch from my result.php, the problem is I do not know how I should write the fetch premise. I've tried to fetch on document.getElementsByName(str.name);

It's the showSearch function that I wan't help with.

I'll post my code and hope someone have a good answear. FYI - I'm not so very good at AJAX.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery    /1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<title>Search</title>

<script>
function showSearch(str)
{
var muffin = document.getElementsByName(str.name);
var xmlhttp;
if(str=="")
{
document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML="";
return;

}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}

 var searchResult ="result.php?area="+muffin+"&arealimiter="+muffin+"&pris="+muffin+"&   prislimiter="+muffin+"&avgift="+muffin+"&avgiftlimiter="+muffin+"&objekttyp="+muffin;
 xmlhttp.open("GET",searchResult,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <h2>
 Hitta bostader!
 </h2>

 <body>
 <?php
 include "functions.php";

 $link = pg_connect("host=xxxx dbname=xxxxx user=xxxx password=xxxxxx");
 $maxarea = pg_query($link, "SELECT MAX(area) FROM bostader");
 $minarea = pg_query($link, "SELECT MIN(area) FROM bostader");
 $maxpris= pg_query($link, "SELECT MAX(pris) FROM bostader");
 $minpris= pg_query($link, "SELECT MIN(pris) FROM bostader");
 $maxavgift = pg_query($link, "SELECT MAX(avgift) FROM bostader");
 $minavgift = pg_query($link, "SELECT MIN(avgift) FROM bostader");
 $rum = pg_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT rum FROM bostader ORDER BY rum");
 $lan = pg_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT lan FROM bostader ORDER BY lan");
 $objekttyp = pg_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT objekttyp FROM bostader ORDER BY objekttyp");
 ?>
 <form id="searchForm" action="">

 <?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["arealimiter"])) {
$isAreaMax = strcmp($_COOKIE["arealimiter"], "min");
}
 ?>
 Area: <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="number" name="area" <?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["area"]))
echo "value=\"".$_COOKIE["area"]."\"";
 ?>min="<?php echo $minarea;?>" max="<?php echo $maxarea;?>"/> <br>
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="arealimiter" value="max"<?php if    ($isAreaMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Max
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="arealimiter" value="min" <?php if (!$isAreaMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Min <br>

Rum: <br>
<?php
$numrum = pg_numrows($rum);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numrum; $i++) {
$row = pg_fetch_array($rum, $i);
echo "<input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rum[]\" value=\"".  $row["rum"]. "\"";
if (isset($_COOKIE["rum".$i]))
    echo " checked";
echo ">". $row["rum"]. "<br>";
 }
 ?> <br>

 <?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["prislimiter"])) {
$isPrisMax = strcmp($_COOKIE["prislimiter"], "min");
}
 ?>

 Pris: <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="number" name="pris"<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["pris"]))
        echo "value=\"".$_COOKIE["pris"]."\"";
 ?>min="<?php echo $minpris;?>" max="<?php echo $maxpris;?>" /> <br>
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="prislimiter" value="max" <?php if ($isPrisMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Max
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="prislimiter" value="min"<?php if (!$isPrisMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Min <br>

 <?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["avgiftlimiter"])) {
$isAreaMax = strcmp($_COOKIE["avgiftlimiter"], "min");
}
 ?>

 Avgift: <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="number" name="avgift"<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["avgift"]))
echo "value=\"".$_COOKIE["avgift"]."\"";
 ?>min="<?php echo $minavgift;?>" max="<?php echo $maxavgift;?>" /> <br>
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="avgiftlimiter" value="max" <?php if ($isAvgiftMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Max
 <input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type="radio" name="avgiftlimiter" value="min"<?php if (!$isAvgiftMax) echo "checked"; ?>>Min <br>

 Lan: <br>
 <?php
 $numlan = pg_numrows($lan);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $numlan; $i++) {
$row = pg_fetch_array($lan, $i);
echo "<input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type=\"checkbox\" name=\"lan[]\" value=\"", $row["lan"]."\"";
if (isset($_COOKIE["lan".$i]))
    echo " checked";
echo ">". $row["lan"]. "<br>";
 }
 ?> <br>

 Objekt Typ: <br>
 <?php
 $numtyp = pg_numrows($objekttyp);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $numtyp; $i++) {
$row = pg_fetch_array($objekttyp, $i);
echo "<input onchange='showSearch(this.value)' type=\"checkbox\" name=\"objekttyp[]\"   value=\"". $row["objekttyp"]."\"";
if (isset($_COOKIE["objekttyp".$i]))
    echo " checked";
echo ">". $row["objekttyp"]. "<br>";
 }
 ?> <br>

 </form>

 <div id="searchDiv">Search result will be displayed here...</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: When are you wanting the search results to show? As soon as the user begins typing, or once they've finished and moved off the search field?

Comment: You should only copy the important parts of your question, otherwise you may not get many useful answers.

Comment: @EmmeramMorning as soon as the users starts to type I belive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you should use the build-in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function rather than reinventing. It looks like you want to run a search every time any `<input>` is changed.

As a starting point I'd use the following jQuery AJAX GET

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        var $form = $('#searchForm'); // a handle to your form element

        function showSearch() { // no need to pass anything to this function
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'result.php',
                data: $form.serialize() // serialize all form elements with a name attribute
            }).done(function(data) {
                // do something with search result, supplied as the "data" variable,
                // in your case just put the results into the `<div id="searchDiv">`
                $('#searchDiv').html(data);
            });
        }

        // Edit: This is the new function

        // bind the showSearch function to the change event of all inputs
        $('#searchForm').on('change', 'input', showSearch);

    });
</script>
```

For a simple example `<form>` - **Edit:** Removed inline event binding

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="one" value="one"/>
    <input text="text" name="two" value="two"/>
</form>
```

This will perform an HTTP GET to `result.php` with the query string `?one=one&two=two`

**Edit:** If you do not want to use jQuery then be prepared for issues developing cross-browser XMLHTTPRequest code! If you really want to keep your code, the only part that you need to change is collecting the *current value* of all the `<input>`s in the `<form>`. You could do this with JavaScript by using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

which will give you an array of your `<input>`s and then loop through, collecting the name and the value from each one:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var querystring = '?';
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    querystring += inputs[i].name + '=' + inputs[i].value + '&';
}

// now remove the last '&' from querystring (or do the above loop differently)
```

As you can see, it's more code that needs developing, testing and could have bugs, which is why I recommended using the simple jQuery [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function :-)

Comment: thnx! But this also implies that I need to cmd+r to get the new values correct? Otherwise it doesn't update...

Comment: And if I don't want to use jquery how should I think?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The JavaScript I wrote can be the body of your `showSearch()` function. I will update my answer. You definitely do not have to use Cmd+R, it can be triggered with `onchange`

Comment: Thank you for really great input, one question though. If i don't pass anything to showSearch() i do get a error-message in firebug : showSearch() not defined. So this implies I do need to pass a parameter to showSearch() ?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I was thinking _everything_ is within the jQuery namespace but you are using the older method of binding events, inline with the HTML. It is cleaner to separate content (HTML) from interaction (JavaScript) - see [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). See my edited answer for cleaner HTML and a simple new JavaScript/jQuery method to attach the `showSearch()` function to your inputs!